# Using CocoaPods and remove some library then get these warnings

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I update my Podfile and delete SBJson then pod install but I got these warnings.

How can I fix these? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for those files in the Xcode file browser (⌘1 in Xcode). They should be red, indicating that they don’t exist. Delete them and the problem should go away.

Make sure you’ve done a `pod install`, as well. I usually do the following when I remove a port:

```
git clean -dxf
pod install
```

This assumes you’re using `git` for source control and don’t have any unstaged changes you care to keep.